# I/O operations - open, modify and save

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

what's the easiest way of opening a file from disk, modify it (adding a blank space) and then save it again?

thanks

Comment: it depends on where the file is located. Client or server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these posts:

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial109_File-operations-IorO.html

http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx

http://www.csharphelp.com/2005/12/simple-text-file-operations-in-c/